# Crop image into circular shape at selected region

Tags: ios

I want to implement a functionality like "add photo" when adding a new contact in iPhone. In iPhone when tapped on "add photo" (When adding new contact) it takes a selected rounded shape from the image. How to implement this functionality in my app?

TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Crop image in Circle Shape with Grid inside Circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53248609/how-to-crop-image-in-circle-shape-with-grid-inside-circle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are probably looking to [mask](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html) your `UIImageView` object. Have a look at this tutorial where `CoreGraphics` were used to resole this problem.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Please provide the link to that tutorial.

Comment: Edited my answer, my bad i forget to provide the link. :)

Comment: Could you please explain how to use it?

Comment: Copy/Paste this function into your code and pass two images to it, source image and masking image. It will return you the masked image.

Comment: It's working fine but this is not i want. I want the exact functionality of adding photo in contacts page. Is there any other way?

Comment: To get more appropriate answer you should post some snap shot for reference.

Comment: Go to contacts in iPhone or iPhone simulator. Tap on + button to add new contact. Then click "Add photo". After selecting pic from gallery you are allowed to select the image with rounded mask. The same i want.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `UIImageView` layer corner radius. Other approach is to override `drawRect:` and draw your custom shape there... except `drawRect:` is not called in `UIImageView`.

From Apple's doc:

> The UIImageView class is optimized to draw its images to the display. UIImageView does not  call the drawRect: method of its subclasses. If your subclass needs to include custom  drawing code, you should subclass the UIView class instead

Once, I did the trick, simply covering the `UIImageView` with the view that had cropped circle inside, so that the impression was the image had a shape of the circle.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  [[UIColor whiteColor] set]; // The background is white
  UIRectFill(rect);

  // self.cropRect is your cropping area, depending on an imageView
  rect = CGRectInset(self.cropRect, 1, 1);

  // The key expression here, makes bezier path drawn in opposite direction
  CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationOut);

  UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:rect.size.width * 0.5f];
  [path fill];

  // Back to normal settings.
  CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);

  [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
  CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rounded corners is the easiest way to go. Otherwise, there is CAShapeLayer which you can set as a mask of the layer of the view you want to crop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get round-cropped (circular) profile images:

I have added a UIImageView in IB and gave it a fix size of 48x48. I've added a method to do the image update which makes the image icon have a round shape with transparent background...

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIImageView* icon;

// ...

- (void)updateIconWithImageData:(NSData*)someImageData
{
    self.icon.image = [UIImage imageWithData:someImageData];
    self.icon.layer.cornerRadius = 24;
    self.icon.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.icon.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
}
```