# How to Crop image in Circle Shape with Grid inside Circle

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

In my Social media app i want image Cropping Functionality, that Crop image in Circle shape plus have Grid inside Circle.[image]

I have Already Checked TOCropViewController.but there is no option for Grid.
https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController

Comment: What is `TOCropViewController`? Is that a third party library? If so you should say that and provide a link.

Comment: This sort of broad "how do I <xyz>?" question is not a good fit for this site. I gave you a very broad answer to your very broad question. Do some research on that, give it a try, and if you have trouble getting it to work, edit your question to show the code you are using, tell us how it is failing to meet your needs, and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: hi @DuncanC thanks for your suggestion i will put link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find one solution , we can use UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext in CropView and use addEllipse method to draw Circle inside CropView.

this is link For Solution.
https://github.com/bhaveshbc/CircleCropView

Comment: Hello. Bhavesh.. 
your library has helped me alot.. do you have an email with which I can contact you?
If yes could leave a message on saurabhsahastrabudhe@gmail.com..

Answer (score 0):

Add a `CAShapeLayer` on top of your cropping view, and add the grid lines in that shape layer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I think Adding CAShapeLayer won't  allow me to move and Zoom image  inside CropView.i found one Solution i will put soon.